# PHP error : undefined offset because of no categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a plugin to manage events on a wordpress website.
Events can be taggued, but they do not have any categories, which leads to an issue.

The listing pages lists those events, but since they dont have any categories it shows an error for the events.

The error :

> NOTICE: UNDEFINED OFFSET: 0 IN /xxxxxxxx/ARCHIVE.PHP ON LINE 39
>   NOTICE: TRYING TO GET PROPERTY OF NON-OBJECT IN /xxxxxxxx/ARCHIVE.PHP ON LINE 39

The php code :

```
<span class="mvp-feat1-cat"><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo esc_html( $category[0]->cat_name ); ?></span>
```

Any idea how to fix this? I am guessing that I should check if `get_the_category()` returns an object or an error or something?

Thanks !

Comment: _"I am guessing that I should check if get_the_category() returns an object or an error or something?"_  sounds good, have you tried it out?

Comment: add a category to it?  I would be hesitant in editing 3rd party (plugin) code if you didn't write it as one update could wipe out any "fixes" you do.  And then one day 6 or 8 months from now your site will mess up and you will have forgotten the specifics about this and have to debug it all over again. If you do have to edit a plugin, one thing that works nice is to copy it / rename it. And then leave the original one installed but not activated. That way you can see when it has updates, and compare those updates to the code you made changes to. I also put a comment block (With my name) by it

Comment: In the code like `/* START:artisticphoenix 2018-11-6 */` and `/* END:artisticphoenix */` that way I can just search through the files for `START:artisticphoenix` and know where my changes are. I won't say I have to fix a lot of plugins, but I do ... lol ...  I just can't abide by notices and warnings on most of my sites... :-)

Comment: @phil : I did try some "isset" codes yesterday, and obviously emptying the cache etc, but I must have done it wrong as it didnt change anything.

Comment: Indeed @ArtisticPhoenix, this is a template file, so there is no risk of losing it with an update of the plugin. 

Thanks though!

Comment: `isset()` won't tell you if an array is empty. For that you want `empty()` or `count()`

Comment: @jeremy - sure, I just wanted to mention my method, sometimes there is no choice but to modify a plugin and it's good to have a plan if you do so.  Even recently I moved some sites built in 5.3 to PHP7 some plugins I had to update were no longer maintained etc.  So it was either edit the plugin or redo the site... lol

Answer (score 0):

What about checking if $category is set (or if get_the_category() instead returns false/null):

```
<span class="mvp-feat1-cat"><?php $category = get_the_category(); if (isset($category) && $category) echo esc_html( $category[0]->cat_name ); ?></span>
```

Edit: I'm guessing archive.php is a theme file, so you should be okay editing it.

Comment: Thanks @cjs1978 I was indeed looking into isset yesterday. I've tried your code too but doesnt seem to work. I made sure to empty the cache before... and still the same. :-(

Comment: I am not sure if that work and it was a cache issue, or another code i added in the functions.php but it seems to have been fixed. It would make sense that the isset works, but it's just that it didnt seem to work the other day

Thanks anyway !